# Change working directory when using "Open with custom command" option

Tags: bash, wine

I was trying to open `.exe` files in Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit edition and `wine 3.0.1` just by double-clicking on the file. I used the "Open with custom command" open with option and issued `wine %f` but it doesn't work fine with applications which requires its files to be in the same directory, as the command is emulated in another terminal with home as working directory. 
 I tried to use `cd "$(dirname %f)" && wine %f` but it doesn't seem to work..

Is there is any way to let it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bash -c 'cd "$(dirname %f)" && wine %f'
```